# How to display the full command history in terminal?

Tags: command-line, big-sur, history

Since updating to Big Sur, the `history` command (terminal) shows only the last 16 commands. Do you have any ideas how to get the full history back?

Comment: Which shell are you using?

Answer (score 14):

I'm assuming that your shell is `zsh`, you can view your whole history by using the following command-

```
history 0
```

Answer (score 2):

I am meeting this issue as well. It seems since recent updates the `history` command is set up to show only a bunch from the most recent entries, instead of the whole command history as it were. I can't seem to get help by RTFM or various attempted commands such as `-h` `--help` etc.

This is impractical for me, I would like to search the whole history using `grep`.
In the meantime a workaround is to `cat ~/.zsh_history`

Answer (score 0):

```
echo 'alias history="history 1"' >> ~/.zshrc && source ~/.zshrc && history
```

Comment: It would be beneficial to other users if you could [edit] in **how** this works and solves the OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to configure your history command to display **full command History** and everything since the start then follow these steps (assuming you have `zsh` shell):

1. Open your Terminal.
2. Make an alias of history to show since the first command, type:

   `echo 'alias history="history 1"' >> ~/.zshrc`
3. Source your configuration file by typing:

   `source ~/.zshrc`
4. Now finally type:

   `history`

Comment: This is a duplicate of an existing answer to the same question https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/463490/221742 albeit split up. Can you explain why your solution is any different? It would have been of more benefit to edit the existing answer and add in the explanation steps.